# How to autosize the height and the width of c# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to auto-size the height and width of a c# windows form? So when I maximize the form all its components are fit to the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `Anchor` property of each control, to snap it to either end of the containing form. then when you resize the form, those anchored controls are resized as well.

Comment: I set the anchor for dataGridView to top, left but its height and width still fixed !!!

Comment: Set the anchor also to bottom and right, then all form edges are "pulling" the dataGridView control with them. If my answer helped you, I'll appreciate if you'll accept it by clicking the "vi" sign next to it

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Anchor, there is also a dock property. This will auto size the controls by docking to one or more sides of the container the control is in, if a control is docked to all sides then it will be 'maximized' to fill its container.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum and maximum size of form as shown below

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(140, 480);
this.MaximumSize = new Size(140, 480);
```

You can also use it as below

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int h = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
            int w = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
            this.ClientSize = new Size(w, h);
        }
```

Another way it can work for you is the

```
Rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
int w = Width >= screen.Width ? screen.Width : (screen.Width + Width) / 2;
int h = Height >= screen.Height ? screen.Height : (screen.Height + Height) / 2;
this.Location = new Point((screen.Width - w) / 2, (screen.Height - h) / 2);
this.Size = new Size(w, h);
```